# Deduplication in R Studio

Tags: r, deduplication

this is my first R Code, and it is a very simple deduplication, but it is working so slowly I can't believe it! My question is: Is it normal that it is working so slowly or is my code just bad? 
Here it is:

```
file1=c(read.delim("file.txt", header=TRUE))   

dedupes<-0
i<-1
n<-1
while (i<=100) {

  while (n<=100) {

    if (file1$email[i]==file1$email[n] && i!=n) { 

    #Remember amount of deduces
      dedupes=dedupes+1
    #Show dedupes 
      print(file1$email[i])             }   

    n<-n+1

  } 

  n<-1
  i<-i+1 

}

#Show amount of dedupes
cat("There are ", dedupes/2, " deduces")
```

Many thanks in advance,
Saitam

Comment: I think it's better to ask such question at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to do: `cat( sum( duplicated(file1$email) ) )`?

Comment: Nice, thank you! I didn't know about that command duplicated() Is there also a possibility to show the name of the duplicates instead of a valse/true value?

Answer (score 0):

Imbricated loops are well known to be slow in R. You need to vectorize your calculus or use existing optimized functions such as in the suggestion of BondedDust

Comment: Thanks for answering, is there also a way to deduplicate without giving attention on small and big letters?